# Загрузка файла асинхронно, на чистом JavaScript

Tags: асинхронность, javascript, upload, файлы

Почему по данному вопросу все предлагают какие-то плагины. Мне интересно как это на чистом js происходит. Не хочу "проще", хочу разобраться.

Сделал без подсказок загрузку в iframe. Но сейчас интересует как отправить на сервер в объекте XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: вас видимо интересует [FileReader.readAsBinaryString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsBinaryString()) и [XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#sendAsBinary()) и вот [для chrome polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#sendAsBinary%28%29_polyfill)  

и тут [немного сэмплов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

инфы надо много перелопатить и начать отсюда можно [xmlhttprequest.ru](http://xmlhttprequest.ru) а потом спецификации POST почитать

Comment: Возможности XmlHttpRequest позволяют создать запрос с любым телом. Например, можно вручную сделать POST-запрос, загружающий на сервер файл. Функционал создания таких запросов есть, в частности, во фреймворке dojo. Но можно реализовать его и самому, прочитав о нужном формате тела POST и заголовках.
======
это и всё что там есть о файлах. Ни ссылок, ни примеров. Ничего.

Comment: эта выдержка никак не противоречит моему ответу:  **инфы надо много перелопатить** и начать отсюда можно xmlhttprequest.ru а потом **спецификации POST** почитать
типы заголовков вот гляньте http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP, готовые примеры к сожалению не могу предложить

Answer (score 3):

Читать тут: [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)! Там и готовый код имеется.

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл тут: [Upload File With Ajax XmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211145/upload-file-with-ajax-xmlhttprequest)

Для тех кому интересно тоже.

Для начала берём input

```
<input type=file name="myFile" id="myFile" />
```

Пдготовим xhr

```
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

var xhr = getXmlHttp()
```

Теперь js-м его выбираем из DOM и отправляем на сервер

```
var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("thefile", file);
xhr.send(formData);
```

На сервере принимаем

```
$_FILES['thefile'] // PHP
```