# Файл в текст или последовательность бит на javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Добрый день, в очередной раз поднимается вопрос о передаче файлов через ajax.
Прочитав множество материалов, просмотрев десятки разных плагинов задался вопросом, а может передать файл через ajax можно преобразовав файл в текст и отправив на сервер через post? Вопрос собственно в том, как выбранный в браузере файл превратить в текст или последовательность бит?

Comment: [HTML5 File API: множественная загрузка файлов на сервер](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109079/) читали?

Comment: Да, но меня больше интересует реализация на основе технологих имеющих чуть более широкое распространение. Я не говорю о том, что HTML5 это не хорошо, это отлично, но по ряду причин мне бы хотелось узнать ответ на вопрос именно в толм контексте, в котором он задан. Но всё-равно благодарю вас за ответ

Comment: @ecko можно по старинке через iframe загрузить.

Comment: @lampa Да, я знаю и именно через скрытый iframe через target я в большинстве случаев отправляю из формы, но вот у меня возник вопрос, а что всё-таки будет, и возможно ли преобразовать выбранный файл в последовательность байт и передачу его через POST

Comment: @ecko опять таки нужен FileReader, который только в html5 стал доступен. По другому вы не разберете файл на байты.

Answer (score 1):

Я задавался вот [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/252086/file-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-javascript?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=252104#252104).